# Qt pure virtual function error

Tags: qt

I'm tring to create an interface with Qt to oblige any subclass to implements two main methods set and get title. But when I try to compile it I get a weird error message that says something about qt_check_for_QOBJECT_macro and staticMetaObject. 
In mainwindow.cpp I have to cast any page to the interface so I can rely on getter and setter methods. 
I don't see any other way to do that.

this is my code:

```
//IPage.h
#ifndef IPAGE_H
#define IPAGE_H

#include <QString>

class IPage
{
public:
 virtual QString title()=0;
 virtual void setTitle(QString t)=0;
};

#endif // IPAGE_H


//buildings.h:
#ifndef BUILDINGS_H
#define BUILDINGS_H

#include "IPage.h"
#include <QDialog>

class Buildings : public IPage, public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT
 private:
   QString m_title;
 //stuff...
};
#endif
//buildings.cpp
//stuff...

void Buildings::setTitle(QString t)
{
   m_title = t;
   setWindowTitle(t);
}

QString Buildings::title()
{
   return m_title;
}

//mainwindow.cpp:
QMdiSubWindow *MainWindow::findChild(const QString &title)
{
    foreach (QMdiSubWindow *window, mdiArea->subWindowList()) {
        IPage *child = qobject_cast<IPage *>(window->widget()); /*line 178*/
        if (child->title() == title)
            return window;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and I get this error message when I compile my code:

```
In file included from c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include/QtCore/qabstractanimation.h:45,
             from c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include/QtCore/QtCore:3,
             from c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include\QtGui/QtGui:3,
             from mainwindow.cpp:1:
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include/QtCore/qobject.h: In function 'T qobject_cast(QObject*) [with T = IPage*]':
mainwindow.cpp:178:   instantiated from here
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include/QtCore/qobject.h:378: error: 'class IPage' has no member named 'qt_check_for_QOBJECT_macro'
c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include/QtCore/qobject.h:380: error: 'class IPage' has no member named 'staticMetaObject'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `D:/Dropbox/Programmi/Qt/Scadenziario'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [build/o/mainwindow.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
01:23:26: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project scadenziario (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

I can't understand error message. I tried to google it, but I can't find any useful informations. 
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

The [meta object compiler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html) requires that the first class you inherit from be the [QObject-derived class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first).

So you should change:

`class Buildings : public IPage, public QDialog`

to:

`class Buildings : public QDialog, public IPage`

Comment: This solution is working. Thanks. But you got a typo we should read: class Buildings : public QDialog, public IPage

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't notice that

Answer (score 2):

When you use `qobject_cast<T *>`, `T` has to inherit from `QObject`. In your case, `T` = `IPage` but `IPage` does not inherit `QObject`. That's why you get the error.

Comment: And how can I fix this error? IPage it's only an interface. I don't need it inherit from QObject. I need to be sure that any implementation of an IPage has getter and setter methods.

Comment: For using `qobject_cast<IPage *>`, `IPage` **has to** inherit from `QObject` : `class IPage : public QObject`. If you don't want to do this, you will have to implement a new method `virtual IPage * IPage::fromQObject(QObject * obj) = 0;` (or something like that) in your `IPage` class (interfaces don't exist in C++).

Answer (score 0):

To add to air-dex's answer:

Because of meta data provided by `QObject`, when casting between `QObject`s RTTI isn't needed which makes the operation faster (and if you use this exclusively, you can turn off RTTI support in your executable making it smaller).  However it is *not* designed to be used the way you are trying to - as a replacement for `dynamic_cast`.  So just change:

```
IPage *child = qobject_cast<IPage *>(window->widget()); /*line 178*/
```

to:

```
IPage *child = dynamic_cast<IPage *>(window->widget()); /*line 178*/
```